# Powershell rename multiple files

Tags: powershell

Example "rename multiple files" gives us this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.txt','.log' }
```

But I need something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.txt','someArray[$i]' }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Take the quotes off and add a $:

EDIT:  Ok, here's my guess.  I don't know what $textfile is, or what result you want exactly.  `[^.jpg]` just means any character except those 4.

```
get-childitem *.jpg | 
Foreach {$i=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.name -replace 'jpg', $textfile[$i++]) -whatif}
```

Comment: OMG! You saved my life! It's working! Thanks you so much!